# How to resolve java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 9 in android

Tags: java, android, malformedurlexception

I am trying to load images in my android application from a url ([http://www.elifeshopping.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/thumbnail (2).jpg](http://www.elifeshopping.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/thumbnail%20%282%29.jpg)) using `BitmapFactory` the code is below :

```
try {
            // ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url)
                    .getContent());
            i.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

here i get

```
05-03 15:57:13.156: W/System.err(1086): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: 9
05-03 15:57:13.167: W/System.err(1086):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:273)
05-03 15:57:13.167: W/System.err(1086):

at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:157).
```

Please help by telling what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Where do you get the url from. Check that your variable url input string starts with either http:// or https:// print the url string in the exception

Comment: i get the url in webservice nd it starts with http only

Comment: You should open the URL connection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used

```
productImgUrl = productImgUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

i replaced all the spaces by `%20`

and its working for me ..

Thanks everybody for their responses

Comment: works for me, I checked in browser it is showing in Image but when I checked in app it shows that Malformed exception, So I added this small code It works fine, It  is not showing error. Thanks @Shruti

Answer (score 2):

> Please help by telling what I am doing wrong.

I think that the problem is that you are calling the `URL` constructor with an invalid URL string.  Indeed, the exception message implies that the URL string starts with "9:".  (The 'protocol' component is the sequence of characters before the first colon character of the URL.)

This doesn't make a lot of sense if the URL string really is:

"http://www.elifeshopping.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/thumbnail (2).jpg"

so I'd infer that it is ... in fact ... something else.  Print it out before you call the `URL` constructor to find out what it really is.

(You should also %-escape the space characters in the URL's path ... but I doubt that will fix this particular exception incarnation.)

Comment: i didn't got this (exception message implies that the URL string starts with "9:". (The 'protocol' component is the sequence of characters before the first colon character.)) ... do i need to edit http ?

Comment: @Shruti - I'm saying that that string is not the one that you are passing to the URL constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Change your url to http://www.elifeshopping.com/images/stories/virtuemart/product/thumbnail%20%282%29.jpg